# Functions of 1 variable not defined using tuples?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**Q** : Does anyone know why functions of a single variable $(x)$ do not have their domain defined with tuples?  Also, why such functions do not always evaluate to a tuple?

For instance, I typically see $f : X \rightarrow Y$, $X=\{x_0,...,x_n\}, Y=\{y_0,...,y_n\}$ where $f(x) = y$  and $f = \{(x_0,y_0),...,(x_n,y_n)\}$.  The arguments $X$ and values $Y$ are not tuples, yet $f(x)$ is defined with a tuple $(x)$ as its argument.  Also, it seems that $f$ must evaluate to a tuple $(y)$ for function composition based on the same reasoning.

I expected to see $X=\{(x_0), ..., (x_n)\}, Y=\{(y_0), ..., (y_n)\}$ where $f(x) = (y)$ and $f = \{((x_0),(y_0)),...,((x_n),(y_n))\}$.  I think I'm missing something; perhaps there is something implicit or historic in this particular case.

Comment: By 'functions of a 1-tuple argument', do you mean functions of one variable?

Comment: @OliverHouse yes

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you are asking, but if we have sets $X$ and $Y$ then a function $f:X\to Y$ acts on individual elements of $X$. There is no need to think of it as a '1-tuple'. The element $x\in X$ is assigned to an element $f(x)\in Y$. Why would you want to enclose the elements within brackets? If you want a function taking $m$-tuples of elements in $X$ to $n$-tuples of elements in $Y$, then you can define a function $(x_1,...,x_m)\mapsto (y_1,...,y_n):X^m\to Y^n$. Then as far as the function is concerned, an $n$-tuple of elements in $X$ is single element in $X^n$

Comment: Not very clear... The usual definition consider a *domain* $X$ and a *codomain* $Y$: thus, input values are **elements** of $X$ and output values are elements of $Y$. From a set-theoretic point of view, the tuple $(x)$ is a more "complex" set, for example a function $f: \{ 1 \} \to X$ and thus is $\{ (1,x) \}$ which does not "live" in $X$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA every element of the domains as an ordered tuple seems to make sense for $V^0, V^2, ...., V^n$, but not $V^1$.  For these cases, I expect $f(), f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$, but in the $V^1$ case I expect $fx$, without the parenthesis.  This makes me wonder if the $V^1$ case is historic when there were no multivariate functions, and it should contain tuples representing the possible arguments $V^1 = \{(a), ..., (b)\}$, which can be substituted as the functions object $f(a)$.  Maybe my curiosity is misguided?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the whole idea of "building tuples" is a 20th century idea, which comes much later than the function notation. My "educated guess" is that people started with "$f(x)$" for a quantity that depended on one variable, and generalized that to depending on multiple variables by just listing the variables, separated by commas, $f(x,y,z)$. I doubt they were thinking about tuples.

Comment: If you are curious about the historical development, there is a separate "history of science" stack exchange where you could ask. Although when presented with claims that "this is inconsistent", history often replies "maybe, but it's what happened". :-)